# AngularJS TemplateURL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, templates

I am trying to integrate angularjs in my rails application to animate the views. I have a single page application and clicking on a link will slide one view out and another into view. Similar to the tutorial described [here](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/animating-angularjs-apps-ngview).

I have successfully added the angular, angular-route, angular-animate to my application. The problem is that i cannot trigger the views. I have removed the `<%= yield %>` from my application.html.erb file to load the view using angularjs and replaced it with `ng-view` as described in the tutorial. The problem i am facing is with:

```
animateApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'static_pages/home',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })
        .when('/locations', {
            templateUrl: 'locations/index',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })
});
```

I am not able to determine the templateUrl of my application and the above code is certainly not working, i cannot get the route to work and i don't want to put my views files inside assets/templates. Please Help.

Comment: Why don't you want to put your views in `assets/templates`? You also might need to put the file extensions on these templateUrls (i.e. `.html`).

Comment: That is not the rails way of making views. I want the Angular JS to work in default rails way.

Comment: If you want to use Angular views, it's going to fall under the blanket of assets. You're going to want to use Angular view if you're using `ngAnimate` because you won't get to use them with regular Rails views. You either want to use the Rails views and then use Angular on top of them ([like this tutorial shows here](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-rails-todo-api-part-1)) or you need to use Angular-driven views in the asset pipeline.